# Can I call the werkzeug debugger in Django without needing to raise an exception or using assertions?

Tags: django, debugging, werkzeug

I'm currently using `Werkzeug` together with `django-extensions` and I'm able to call the `werkzeug` debugger by raising an exception or making a false assertion. Is it possible to just set a breakpoint for `werkzeug` like `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()` does?